# Resetting a user's password as admin results in 'Password Reset Failed'

Tags: password

I am logged onto a 2013 Macbook Air trying to reset a user's password. This user is not logged in, and is not an admin themselves (they were before, which was revoked). When I reset the user's password it fails with `Password Reset Failed`. Trying to do so in the terminal with `passwd username` prompts for the old password.

Comment: Have you tried the GUI approach through System Preferences > Users & Groups? You'll need to authenticate by clicking on the Lock icon using Administrator account credentials.

Comment: Which OS version are you running?

Comment: @TimCampbell this version is Catalina Version 10.15.7.